# Why mma always automatically created a folder named "Wolfram Mathematica" after renamed or deleted?

Tags: configuration

The folder "Wolfram Mathematica" is probably used for saving files.But each time I renamed or deleted it and then ran mma,mma was bound to automatically create the previous folder "Wolfram Mathematica".

Related info:

1. OS:Windows 10 Home 19043.1466
2. MMA:Wolfram Mathematica 12.3.1
3. The folder path:"C:\Users\Charles\Documents\Wolfram Mathematica"

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica StackExchange. This question has been raised before. Check questions [Change "Wolfram Mathematica" directory](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/258730/change-wolfram-mathematica-directory/258732#258732) and [Prevent 10.2 from creating "Wolfram Mathematica" directory on Linux](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/89369/prevent-10-2-from-creating-wolfram-mathematica-directory-on-linux).

Comment: I suggest you contact Wolfram, Inc.

Comment: See https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/573855

Comment: All right,I see what you said.
https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1946924
@bbgodfrey